# How to add elements to an array without using ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm working on an assignment where I need to take create an array based on user inputs. The first item in the array is an original value (xmin), and subsequent numbers are the previous number plus another user inputted value (incretement). So if xmin is 1 and incretement is 2, the array would be { 1, 3, 5, 7 } etc, and the program fills the array up to length n (another user input). The code for this part works currently but I just realized we're not allowed to use StringBuilder, Arrays class (so no ArrayList), or any class in java.util.stream.

The second part of the assignment is to create a second array of y values based on the array of x values. So I would have to read each value of the x array, apply a function to it, and put the new value in the y array. The code for this section isn't working.

```
ArrayList<Double> x = new ArrayList<Double>();
x.add(xmin);
    
int i;
double value = xmin;
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    value += increment;
    x.add(value);
}
        
ArrayList<Double> y = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    double read = x[i];
    double yValue = 20 * Math.abs(Math.sin(x));
    y.add(yValue);
}
```

Comment: Java arrays have a single, static size. You cannot increase the size of an array after creating it. You could copy the *contents* of an array to a new, bigger array.

Comment: Other than that, there are errors in your code. Like passing `x` to `Math.sin` instead of `read`. But the compiler will tell you what and where those are.

Comment: Could I fill the array with zeroes and then change the values afterward? The length of the array is the first value we get from the user so it wouldn't have any contents yet.

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: You don't even have to fill a _primitive_ number array (e.g., `double[]`) with zeros, as that will be the default value of each element for such arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you read `n` before you start filling the array? If yes, you can simply do

```
double[] x = new double[n];
x[0] = xmin;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
  x[i] = x[i-1] + increment;

double[] y = new double[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  y[i] = 20 * Math.abs(Math.sin(x[i]));
```

You don't even need to preinitialize the values of your arrays, because they will be filled with the default value of `0`

Answer (score 0):

You asked many Questions at once. Better ask one Question after another.
As for your Question in the title

"How to add elements to an array without using ArrayList"
This depends on when you need this new Array and when do you know how much elements you want to add. If you dont know both i would do it this way:

```
double[] addElement(double[] array, double elementToAdd)
    {
        double[] result = new double[array.length+1];
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) 
            result[i]=array[i];
        result[result.length-1]=elementToAdd;
        return result;
    }
```